# Integrating Kaltura Player API in drupal

Tags: kaltura

```
kaltura_player:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/{partner_id}/sp/{partner_id}00/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/%uiconf_id%/partner_id/{partner_id}


{% set uiconf_id = 12345 %}
 
{{
    attach_library('your_module_or_theme_name/kaltura_player')
    |replace({'%uiconf_id%': uiconf_id}) 
}}
```

If you need to pass the `uiconf_id` parameter dynamically from `Twig` to the `Drupal` library.

You can do so by defining the `uiconf_id` parameter as a placeholder in the library definition and replacing it with the actual value in the `Twig` template.